# Where is 'UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' in Spring Boot 2.0.0?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to upgrade an existing project to Spring 5 and Spring Boot 2.0.0.  There is a class that extends `UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory`, which is supposed to be in the `org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.undertow` package.  However, I can't see this package or interface in the current Spring Boot 2.0.0.M1/M2/M3/BUILD-SNAPSHOT.  The documentation still seems to reference this interface [API Docs](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/undertow/UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.html).

Has this interface been replaced by something else?

The original code:

```
import io.github.jhipster.config.JHipsterConstants;
import io.github.jhipster.config.JHipsterProperties;
import io.github.jhipster.web.filter.CachingHttpHeadersFilter;

import com.codahale.metrics.MetricRegistry;
import com.codahale.metrics.servlet.InstrumentedFilter;
import com.codahale.metrics.servlets.MetricsServlet;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.*;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.*;//.UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory;
import io.undertow.UndertowOptions;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.*;

/**
 * Configuration of web application with Servlet 3.0 APIs.
 */
@Configuration
public class WebConfigurer implements ServletContextInitializer, EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebConfigurer.class);

    private final Environment env;

    private final JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties;

    private MetricRegistry metricRegistry;

    public WebConfigurer(Environment env, JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties) {

        this.env = env;
        this.jHipsterProperties = jHipsterProperties;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        if (env.getActiveProfiles().length != 0) {
            log.info("Web application configuration, using profiles: {}", (Object[]) env.getActiveProfiles());
        }
        EnumSet<DispatcherType> disps = EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.ASYNC);
        initMetrics(servletContext, disps);
        if (env.acceptsProfiles(JHipsterConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_PRODUCTION)) {
            initCachingHttpHeadersFilter(servletContext, disps);
        }
        if (env.acceptsProfiles(JHipsterConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT)) {
            initH2Console(servletContext);
        }
        log.info("Web application fully configured");
    }

    /**
     * Customize the Servlet engine: Mime types, the document root, the cache.
     */
    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
        MimeMappings mappings = new MimeMappings(MimeMappings.DEFAULT);
        // IE issue, see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/711
        mappings.add("html", "text/html;charset=utf-8");
        // CloudFoundry issue, see https://github.com/cloudfoundry/gorouter/issues/64
        mappings.add("json", "text/html;charset=utf-8");
        container.setMimeMappings(mappings);
        // When running in an IDE or with ./gradlew bootRun, set location of the static web assets.
        setLocationForStaticAssets(container);

        /*
         * Enable HTTP/2 for Undertow - https://twitter.com/ankinson/status/829256167700492288
         * HTTP/2 requires HTTPS, so HTTP requests will fallback to HTTP/1.1.
         * See the JHipsterProperties class and your application-*.yml configuration files
         * for more information.
         */
        if (jHipsterProperties.getHttp().getVersion().equals(JHipsterProperties.Http.Version.V_2_0) &&
            container instanceof UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {

            ((UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container)
                .addBuilderCustomizers(builder ->
                    builder.setServerOption(UndertowOptions.ENABLE_HTTP2, true));
        }
    }

    private void setLocationForStaticAssets(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
        File root;
        String prefixPath = resolvePathPrefix();
        root = new File(prefixPath + "build/www/");
        if (root.exists() && root.isDirectory()) {
            container.setDocumentRoot(root);
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Resolve path prefix to static resources.
     */
    private String resolvePathPrefix() {
        String fullExecutablePath = this.getClass().getResource("").getPath();
        String rootPath = Paths.get(".").toUri().normalize().getPath();
        String extractedPath = fullExecutablePath.replace(rootPath, "");
        int extractionEndIndex = extractedPath.indexOf("build/");
        if(extractionEndIndex <= 0) {
            return "";
        }
        return extractedPath.substring(0, extractionEndIndex);
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the caching HTTP Headers Filter.
     */
    private void initCachingHttpHeadersFilter(ServletContext servletContext,
                                              EnumSet<DispatcherType> disps) {
        log.debug("Registering Caching HTTP Headers Filter");
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic cachingHttpHeadersFilter =
            servletContext.addFilter("cachingHttpHeadersFilter",
                new CachingHttpHeadersFilter(jHipsterProperties));

        cachingHttpHeadersFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(disps, true, "/content/*");
        cachingHttpHeadersFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(disps, true, "/app/*");
        cachingHttpHeadersFilter.setAsyncSupported(true);
    }

    /**
     * Initializes Metrics.
     */
    private void initMetrics(ServletContext servletContext, EnumSet<DispatcherType> disps) {
        log.debug("Initializing Metrics registries");
        servletContext.setAttribute(InstrumentedFilter.REGISTRY_ATTRIBUTE,
            metricRegistry);
        servletContext.setAttribute(MetricsServlet.METRICS_REGISTRY,
            metricRegistry);

        log.debug("Registering Metrics Filter");
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic metricsFilter = servletContext.addFilter("webappMetricsFilter",
            new InstrumentedFilter());

        metricsFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(disps, true, "/*");
        metricsFilter.setAsyncSupported(true);

        log.debug("Registering Metrics Servlet");
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic metricsAdminServlet =
            servletContext.addServlet("metricsServlet", new MetricsServlet());

        metricsAdminServlet.addMapping("/management/metrics/*");
        metricsAdminServlet.setAsyncSupported(true);
        metricsAdminServlet.setLoadOnStartup(2);
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = jHipsterProperties.getCors();
        if (config.getAllowedOrigins() != null && !config.getAllowedOrigins().isEmpty()) {
            log.debug("Registering CORS filter");
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/api/**", config);
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/v2/api-docs", config);
        }
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }

    /**
     * Initializes H2 console.
     */
    private void initH2Console(ServletContext servletContext) {
        log.debug("Initialize H2 console");
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic h2ConsoleServlet = servletContext.addServlet("H2Console", new org.h2.server.web.WebServlet());
        h2ConsoleServlet.addMapping("/h2-console/*");
        h2ConsoleServlet.setInitParameter("-properties", "src/main/resources/");
        h2ConsoleServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    }

    @Autowired(required = false)
    public void setMetricRegistry(MetricRegistry metricRegistry) {
        this.metricRegistry = metricRegistry;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` has been renamed in 2.0. It's now [`UndertowServletWebServerFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/boot/web/embedded/undertow/UndertowServletWebServerFactory.html). I noticed that you're also using `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer`. Its equivalent in 2.0 is `org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizer`.

Comment: This has a bunch of other Spring renamings in the JHipster generator code https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/6274/commits/37fc3f20059930316c7d5f07a618d6a0c6e2c631